# How to resolve jquery module error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, intellij-idea, bower, yeoman

I have a YeoMan project on IntelijIdea, and I have jquery 2.1.4 installed. My bower module is underlined with red, meaning that at line 8284 in jquery.js, I have this :

[image]

line 8284 jQuery.**active** --> unresolved write property

line 8066 jQuery.**active** --> unresolved write property

I tried "**bower install**" , "**bower update**", restart Idea

**Bower.json**

```
{
  "name": "enterprise-edition",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.3.0",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.4",
    "angular-animate": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-cookies": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-resource": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-route": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-sanitize": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-touch": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-ui-router": "~0.2.18",
    "angular-bootstrap": "~1.2.4",
    "fsm-sticky-header": "*",
    "jquery": "2.1.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "^1.3.0"
  },
  "appPath": "app",
  "moduleName": "enterpriseEditionApp",
  "resolutions": {
    "bootstrap": "4.0",
    "angular": "^1.0.8"
  }
}
```